# Having an rbenv config issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I believe I am having an rbenv config issue. In the past I have used `rvm` with Bash, but since I stopped working with Ruby on Rails on a commercial level, I have switched over to zsh and I can no longer use `rvm`.

I have tried to start up a project on a machine that I have always used to run Rails and got this error:

```
rails s
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I followed the above and got this:

```
sudo gem install rails
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
```

Now let me run down the line of everything I did:

```
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) rbenv global 2.4.4
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) rbenv rehash
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) rvm install 2.4.4
zsh: command not found: rvm
```

Everything I did above is following the commentary of a similar post that was never given an answer. I am on a mid-2015 MacBook Pro (High Sierra).

`ruby -v` is giving me `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]`. But when I do `rbenv install 2.4.4` it just goes through what seems an installation process and I am back to where I started again.

Actually now it tells me `rbenv: /Users/danale/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4 already exists.`

This is what my `~/.zshenv` looks like:

```
 export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  1 eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: @Joel_Blum, `ruby -v` is giving me `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]`. But when I do `rbenv install 2.4.4` it just goes through what seems an installation process and I am back to where I started again. Actually it tells me `rbenv: /Users/danale/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4 already exists`.

Comment: so it seems like a rbenv config issue, you may wanna rephrase your question.

Comment: you can try rbenv local 2.4.4 , maybe there's already a local version from your current dir?

Comment: otherwise rbenv has a doctor script to troubleshoot, maybe it wasn't installed well. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer#readme

Answer (score 0):

Okay so these are the steps I had to follow:

1. `brew update`
2. `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
   Which eventually gave me this error:

```
Error: ruby-build 20180822 is already installed
To upgrade to 20200401, run `brew upgrade ruby-build`.
```

3. `brew upgrade ruby-build`

Which lead to the following:

```
   ✗ rails s
    Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

        $ sudo gem install rails

    You can then rerun your "rails" command.
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ sudo gem install rails
    Password:
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ vim ~/.zshenv
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ vim ~/.zshrc
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ source ~/.zshrc
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
    ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin17]
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ sudo gem install rails
    Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.1.6.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.6
    Fetching: i18n-1.8.2.gem (100%)

    HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
    But that may break your application.

    If you are upgrading your Rails application from an older version of Rails:

    Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
    If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
    'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
    If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.

    If you are starting a NEW Rails application, you can ignore this notice.

    For more info see:
    https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0

    Successfully installed i18n-1.8.2
    Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.6.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
    Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.7.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.7
    Fetching: zeitwerk-2.3.0.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed zeitwerk-2.3.0
    Fetching: activesupport-6.0.2.2.gem (100%)
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.5.0.
    ➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ rails s
    rbenv: rails: command not found

    The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
      2.5.1

gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-2.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
1 gem installed
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin17]
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ rbenv global 2.5.1
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin17]
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.4.4 (set by /Users/danale/Projects/alpha-blog/.ruby-version)
  2.5.1
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ rbenv local 2.5.1
➜  alpha-blog git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
```